# CSS Horizontal Rule to be full width & adjust to screen size

Tags: css, wordpress, containers

I am truly stuck with this, basically I am using wordpress, and want a horizontal line to go across the page (breaking out of the inside container). This line should adjust to the screen size, so if you zoom out the line should keep getting longer, basically an infinate line.

So far the what i've managed to do is the following code:

```
.horizontalrule1 {
    position:relative;
    height:82px;
    background: #f1f2f2;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:600%;
    margin-left: -100%;
}
```

This technically looks fine but the issue is it's causing a scroller to appear at the bottom of the page because the width is set at 600%

If I set the width to 100% it doesnt make the line full width and stops it at the inside container which is about 990px.

All I want is an infinate line that will adjust itself to the screen size, so if you have a screen width of 1900px the line should be 1900px etc.

Hope this makes sense.

My html is:

```
<div class="horizontalrule1"></div>
```

To give everyone a better idea of what i want, check out [onlywire.com](http://onlywire.com), they have thick grey horizontal rules that stretch accross the site. This is exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Just edited in my html

Comment: @user3096485 do you have an url we can check with?

Answer (score 0):

You want it to go OUTSIDE the DOM element?

```
.elementContainingYourHorizontalRule {
    overflow: auto; /* or whatever, just don't set it to hidden. */
    position: relative;
}

.horizontalrule1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300%;
    height: 2px; /* or whatever. */
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do things -- if I were you, I'd make your containing element go the full width of the page and let your custom HR do it's own thing automatically. I understand that may not work with your design/layout though.

At any rate, your horizontal rule will never be able to know your page width if you don't give the container the full width as well. So you're stuck with an ugly 600% hardcode until you get your container full-width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ive tried changing the container element to full width but then unfortunately everything thats inside that container is full width such as text etc. To give you an example of how I want it to look, go to onlywire.com and youll see they have these thick grey horizontal rules across their site, but all of their text and other content is displayed inside the container.

Comment: Thats exactly what I need, I'll give that a try and hopefully it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this which should force it outside the surrounding container using negative horizontal margins:

```
hr {
    margin: 20px -10000px;
}
```

And to avoid horizontal scrollbar add this to body:

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If you only want to apply it to specific horizontal rulers, add it as a class.

**HTML:**

```
  <hr class="full">
```

**In Style Sheet:**

```
 hr.full {
 margin: 20px -10000px;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While answers are always appreciated, please note that this question was asked 3 years ago, and the question asker has probably **long** since solved the problem. If you're looking to answer active questions, you may benefit from checking the list of the [**newest questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest). I'd also recommend checking out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Answer (score -1):

You should set your body's padding and margin to 0 :

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: The body padding & margins are set to 0.